# Как увеличить размер шрифта интерфейса в программе ramus (на java)?

Tags: java

[ramus](https://github.com/Vitaliy-Yakovchuk/ramus) - это редактор idef0-схем ОС Fedora 30,  с kde.

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 2):

Надеюсь, я вас правильно понял: **`Сервис` ⇒ `Свойства программы`**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Прочие шрифты зашиты внутри программы в `html` файлах и не настраиваются в интерфейсе пользователя. Нужно дорабатывать код программы.